# Creating a text field that dynamically resizes its width

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm making what is basically a toolbar that contains a search field and some buttons. I'd like for the search field to grow in size (just the width) when the parent container gets wider, like when the user adjusts the split pane. Currently, the text field and the buttons will remain the same size and whitespace is added on either side as the container is widened. I can achieve this growing effect by using a `BorderLayout` in the container and putting the buttons on `LINE_END` and the text field in the `CENTER`. The problem I have with this is that the text field now becomes taller than a standard text field and it looks ugly. This behavior makes sense as the `BorderLayout` manager will give all the extra space (this includes vertical and hortizontal space) to the `CENTER` text field. I've tried to restrict this vertical growth by placing a maximum size on the text field, but `BorderLayout` will not honor it.

Here's what I've got:

```
final JTextField searchField = new JTextField("Enter your search terms");
searchField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 25));
final JPanel controls = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
controls.add(searchField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
controls.add(new JPanel(){{
    add(new JButton("Search")); add(new JButton("I'm Feeling Lucky"));
}}, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

It would seem that this behavior is a commonly desired one and it should be easy to implement, but I've had no luck after looking through all the Oracle/Sun tutorials and Google search results.

Anybody have any solutions to this? I need to stick with standard Java Swing components - no third party libraries please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use GridBagLayout , it is complicated but it is the most powerful layout.. When you learn it, you would not have any layout issue.

Here is the sample use of gridbaglayout for this question...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutExample extends JFrame {

    GridBagLayoutExample() {
        initUI();
    }


    private void initUI() {
        final JTextField searchField = new JTextField("Enter your search terms"); 
        final JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); 
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx=1.0;
        c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        controls.add(searchField,c); 
        controls.add(new JPanel(){
            {     
            add(new JButton("Search")); add(new JButton("I'm Feeling Lucky")); }}); 
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagLayoutExample().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how to use `GridBagLayout` to achieve this effect? That would be a good introduction to learning this layout manager.

Comment: Excellent! That was a lot less painful then I was expecting; thanks for your help.

Comment: as I said gridbaglayout is a must for every swing programmer.

Comment: GridBagLayout only for a masochists ;-) There are 3rd party layoutManagers available which are both more powerful and more easy to use, f.i. any of the "big three" FormLayout, MigLayout, DesignLayout

Comment: I agree with kleopatra here. I got seriously made on any default, even on Grid or GridBag-layout managers after a project where I was required to change number and position of elements depending on user selections. The default layouts are just anti-dynamic by nature. For me helpful here was TableLayout. BTW anyone knows what is up with this project recently I couldn't get on their page?! Good luck, Boro.

Answer (score 1):

it's a two part problem:

a) all xxSize (xx = min/max/pref) are mere *hints* to the LayoutManager. Each and every LayoutManager has its own behaviour if/how/when it respects those hints and if/how/when it violates one or more if the overall space is more or less than would fit the sum of pref for all components in the container. No way but learn which does what (documentation is ... ehem ... suboptimal)

b) JTextField is a bit crazy in allowing its height to grow indefinitely if space allows. Implying that even LayoutManagers which respect max (like f.i. BoxLayout) have no chance to do so, max is Integer.MAX_VALUE (or Short.MAX? forgot). To make it behave, subclass and override maxSize to return the pref height:

```
@Override
Dimension getMaximumSize() {
   Dimension max = super.getMaximumSize();
   max.height = getPreferredSize().height; 
   return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a horizontal BoxLayout.

```
searchField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 25));
```

You should not guess at the height of the text field.

```
Dimension d = searchField.getPreferredSize();
d.width = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
searchField.setMaximumSize(d);
```

I know you said you don't want to use 3rd party libraries, but as a side note you might want to look at [Text Field Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/). It allows you to display a message that will disapear when you start typing in the text field.

Comment: I'll take another look at `BoxLayout`. Perhaps you could provide a little more information than that?

Comment: you definitely know better than suggest using api that's never-never touch in app development :-) SetXXSize is off-limits, always and ever

Answer (score 0):

Using [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

```
JTextField search_field = new JTextField("Enter search term");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
panel.add(search_field);
```

This will dynamically change the size of textfield when resizing the frame.