# How to have a Java Spinner with left and right arrows?

Tags: java, spinner

I've used java Spinner in Java Swing, but it had up and down arrows, is there a way to set it's orientation so that the arrows are left and right ?

Thanks to Jean-François Savard's answer, I'm one step closer, but still not quite right, I have the following lines :

```
  public void installUI(JComponent c)
  {
    super.installUI(c);
    c.removeAll();
    FlowLayout FL=new FlowLayout();
    FL.setHgap(0);
    c.setLayout(FL);
    JComponent editor=createEditor();
    editor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,16));
    c.add(editor);
    c.add(createPreviousButton());
    c.add(createNextButton());
  }
```

The spacing is not correct, how to fix it ? I hard coded in the above lines, how to automatically provide proper space for the text ?

Answer (score 4):

A short search on google lead me to a custom implementation of `JSpinner` to do this.

```
public class LeftRightSpinnerDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        new LeftRightSpinnerDemo().makeUI();
      }
    });
  }

  public void makeUI() {
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    spinner.setUI(new LeftRightSpinnerUI());

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(spinner);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class LeftRightSpinnerUI extends BasicSpinnerUI {

  public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
    return new LeftRightSpinnerUI();
  }

  @Override
  protected Component createNextButton() {
    Component c = createArrowButton(SwingConstants.EAST);
    c.setName("Spinner.nextButton");
    installNextButtonListeners(c);
    return c;
  }

  @Override
  protected Component createPreviousButton() {
    Component c = createArrowButton(SwingConstants.WEST);
    c.setName("Spinner.previousButton");
    installPreviousButtonListeners(c);
    return c;
  }

  // copied from BasicSpinnerUI
  private Component createArrowButton(int direction) {
    JButton b = new BasicArrowButton(direction);
    Border buttonBorder = UIManager.getBorder("Spinner.arrowButtonBorder");
    if (buttonBorder instanceof UIResource) {
      b.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(buttonBorder, null));
    } else {
      b.setBorder(buttonBorder);
    }
    b.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
    return b;
  }

  @Override
  public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    c.removeAll();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    c.add(createNextButton(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    c.add(createPreviousButton(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    c.add(createEditor(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}
```

Make sure to add the correct `import`s as I removed them to lighten the code.

Refer to [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/522480/GUI/java/change-jspinner-arrows-left) for the original post.

Comment: Can you post the link?

Comment: Awesome, I may use this for my own project :)

Comment: Glad to hear it help :)

Comment: Great, but I want the 2 arrows together on the right side, just like the original spinner, like this :   [ text  < > ]

Comment: @Frank then simply modify the UI, I'm sure you can figure out looking at the `installUI` method :)

Comment: @Jean-François Savard : Thanks, I tried to change that, see my edited question above, the spacing isn't exactly right, how to fix it ?

Comment: @Frank try to call `setHgap(0)` on your `FlowLayout`.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard : I tried, but when the number goes down to negative, it doesn't show correctly, how to widen the text field side ?

Comment: @Frank you might want to read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555355/creating-a-text-field-that-dynamically-resizes-its-width

Comment: +1 Helpful . If you don't mind, can you update your code so that `setModel()` doesn't raise the error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: unknown constraint: Editor`. It took me few hours until I found the solution [here](https://coderanch.com/t/607817/java/problems-custom-JSpinner-UI)